# Obter coordenadas, medir distâncias e compará-las

Tags: javascript, google-maps, geolocalização, coordenadas

Foi-me proposto desenvolver uma página onde esta apresenta um excerto do Google Maps com diversos marcadores organizados em clusters (feito).
Não tenho experiência com JavaScript, e o que preciso é que ao clicar num botão (ou não), seja possível obter a minha localização e automaticamente ser informado de qual o ponto marcado no mapa está mais perto de mim.

Alguém me consegue ajudar?

```js
function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 13,
    center: {
      lat: 40.963308,
      lng: -8.594651
    }
  });

  // Create an array of alphabetical characters used to label the markers.
  var labels = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';

  // Add some markers to the map.
  // Note: The code uses the JavaScript Array.prototype.map() method to
  // create an array of markers based on a given "locations" array.
  // The map() method here has nothing to do with the Google Maps API.
  var markers = locations.map(function(location, i) {
    return new google.maps.Marker({
      position: location,
      label: labels[i % labels.length]
    });
  });

  // Add a marker clusterer to manage the markers.
  var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers, {
    imagePath: 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/m'
  });
}

var locations = [{
    lat: 40.962157,
    lng: -8.593313
  },
  {
    lat: 40.962149,
    lng: -8.595695
  },
  {
    lat: 40.960351,
    lng: -8.598922
  },
  {
    lat: 40.967305,
    lng: -8.591450
  },
  {
    lat: 40.961682,
    lng: -8.608136
  }
]
```

Comment: Mas você quer mostrar isso no mapa, ou quer simplesmente saber o mais proximo?

Comment: Saber o mais próximo é o mais importante, mas se for possível mostrar no mapa também seria excelente!

Answer (score 1):

Fiz uma logica para você conseguir calcular a distancia, e dessa maneira você consegue saber qual o mais proximo e ate pegar a `latitude` e `longitude` desse para mostrar no mapa.

```js
let atual = [-23.573037, -46.650190]
function calc(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2){
        let R = 6371
 let dLat = (lat2 - lat1) * (Math.PI / 180)
 let dLon = (lon2 - lon1) * (Math.PI / 180)

 let a = Math.sin(dLat / 2) * Math.sin(dLat / 2) + Math.cos(lat1 * (Math.PI / 180)) * Math.cos(lat2 * (Math.PI / 180)) * Math.sin(dLon / 2) * Math.sin(dLon / 2)
 let c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1 - a))
 let d = R * c

 return d
}

function getGeo(position){
 alert('A distancia entre os prontos é de: ' + calc(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude, atual[0], atual[1]))
}

function error() {
 alert("Erro")
}

let options = {
 enableHighAccuracy: true, 
 maximumAge        : 30000, 
 timeout           : 27000
}

let wpid = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(getGeo, error, options)
```

Basta adaptar da forma que melhor lhe conver ;)